# How to get filename and extension when opening email attachment

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I have created an intent filter to associate my activity with a custom file extension. This works OK: the mail app starts my activity for an attachment with the custom extension.

In the activity I read the Intent like so:

```
Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
```

and I can open an inputstream OK, but I would like to know the filename and extension for the attachment. Any way to get this from the Uri ?

I tried getting this information via a cursor, but the mail app seems to have only two columns: _id and _data, not something that could be related to the filename and or extension.

I know I cannot access the actual file, but need to know the name of the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you perform a query with the given Uri, the cursor has 4 columns: `_id`, `_data`, `_display_name` and `_size`. The `_display_name` is the filename with extension.

Source: AOSP Email Application

[AttachmentUtilities.Columns](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.3_r2.1/com/android/emailcommon/utility/AttachmentUtilities.java#AttachmentUtilities.Columns) - Columns used when query the attachment Uri

[AttachmentProvider](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.3_r2.1/com/android/email/provider/AttachmentProvider.java#AttachmentProvider.query%28android.net.Uri%2Cjava.lang.String%5B%5D%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%5B%5D%2Cjava.lang.String%29) - Attachment Provider implementation